Laravel WebPush Notification in command foreach not working only the toWebPush
My command code
public function handle()
    {
        // $user = User::find(1);
        // $user->notify(new NotifikasiUmurAnakLimaTahun("Fahrizal", "Posyandu 1"));
        try {
            $anak = Anak::whereRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tgl_lahir, CURDATE()) > 5')->get();
            foreach ($anak as $a) {
                DB::transaction(function () use ($a) {
                    // $a->delete();
                    // $a->dihapus_sebab = "Umur anak lebih 5 tahun";
                    // $a->save();
                });
                $petugasPosyandu = User::where('jenis_pengguna_id', 2)->get();
                $ortu = User::find($a->pengguna_id);
                $posyandu = Posyandu::find($a->posyandu_id);
                $petugasPosyandu->each->notify(new NotifikasiUmurAnakLimaTahunPetugas($a->nama));
                Log::info($a->nama);
                Log::info($posyandu->nama);
                $ortu->notify(new NotifikasiUmurAnakLimaTahun($a->nama, $posyandu->nama));
            }
            $this->info('Cek umur anak selesai');
            Log::info('CheckUmurAnak command executed successfully.');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error executing CheckUmurAnak command: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return 1; // Return a non-zero exit code to indicate failure
        }

        return 0; // Return a zero exit code to indicate success
    }

My Class Code
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use NotificationChannels\WebPush\WebPushChannel;
use NotificationChannels\WebPush\WebPushMessage;

class NotifikasiUmurAnakLimaTahun extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $namaAnak;
    protected $posyandu;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($namaAnak, $posyandu)
    {
        $this->namaAnak = $namaAnak;
        $this->posyandu = $posyandu;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [WebPushChannel::class];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Pemberitahuan bahwa anak anda telah lulus dari posyandu')
            ->greeting('Halo, SiYandu ingin memberitahukan bahwa : ')
            ->line("Anak anda yang bernama {$this->namaAnak} telah berusia lebih dari 5 tahun.")
            ->line("dengan demikian, maka {$this->namaAnak} telah lulus dari Posyandu {$this->posyandu}, selamat")
            ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
            ->line('Terima kasih!');
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' => "Anak anda bernama {$this->namaAnak} telah lulus dari posyandu {$this->posyandu} karena telah berusia lebih dari 5 tahun.",
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
    public function toWebPush($notifiable, $notification)
    {
        return (new WebPushMessage)
            ->title('Pemberitahuan Umur Anak')
            ->body("Anak anda bernama {$this->namaAnak} telah lulus dari posyandu {$this->posyandu} karena telah berusia lebih dari 5 tahun.")
            ->icon(asset('images/LogoSiYanduF1FADA.png'))
            ->badge(asset('images/LogoSiYanduF1FADA.png'))
            ->action('View', 'view_action')
            ->options(['TTL' => 1000]);
    }
}


why the notify code especially the toWebPush is not working when i code it inside the foreach, in the command code, the code that i comment is working, but when i take it inside the foreach, it doesnt work. Nothing wrong with the data
is there any other option to make this works? i need the foreach to fetch the $anak data where i take it from database
